# Junit test cases for a nested do while loop

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, junit4

Here is the skeletal for the code:

```
    flag1=True
    flag2=True
    do {

        try {

            if (){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            .
            .
            .
           do {

                if () {


                } 
               else {

                }
                .
                . 
                .
                if () {
                }

            } while (flag2);

            flag1 = false;

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {

            flag1 = true;
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            flag1 = true;


        } catch (Error ex) {

            flag1= true;
        }
        }

    } while (flag1);
}
```

I am using junit4 for testing. I need to cover all the try catch blocks for testing as well. 
I wrote a test case satisfying the first if condition and hence throwing illegal argument exception, but after throwing the exception the code moves to the do loop with flag1 always staying true.

Answer (score 0):

To start off it sounds like you might be a Java beginner. If that's the case, let me suggest reading up on exception handling in Java. I think that will make it easy for you to understand the cause of this behavior. Here are some quick tutorials on that topic from Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

With that said, here is my explanation of what is causing the behavior you described: 1. `flag1` remains true. 2. looping doesn't stop.

1.
The reason why `flag1` is not set to true is that when IllegalArgumentException is thrown, all code between the place it is thrown and the exception catch blocks will be skipped. This includes skipping the line `flag1 = false;`.

2.
The reason the while loops do not exit when IllegalArgumentException is thrown is that IllegalArgumentException inherits from RuntimeException as you can see here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html . This means that your catch block `catch (RuntimeException ex)` will catch the thrown exception. Thus, what will happen is that the code in the RuntimeException catch block (`retry = true;`) will be executed and then the execution will continue from after the try-catch block. Since this is still inside the outer do-while loop, looping will continue.